# Conceptual svn knowledge about merging/committing needed

Tags: svn

I'm  still learning the basics of svn, and there are a couple of concepts I'm unsure of, so I need some clarification.  I have read dozens of pages of the SVN book, as well as dozens of stackoverflow threads, and I'm still at a loss.

My situation:  I'm using svn (1.6.17) on the command line.  The project I'm working on has a TRUNK (for code ready for release) and I have my own dev BRANCH, and of course, a working copy (WC).

My workflow is:

1. Merge TRUNK -> WC  (most often, files that other devs have updated are received)

2. Edit and test WC files

3. Commit to BRANCH

The problem I'm having is, that files that other devs have edited (and I have not touched) are being committed to my BRANCH and appear (via WebSVN) as being my edits.  So, even if I only edit one file, it looks like I've touched lots of files.

Is this normal?  How can I get the files that other people edit to go to my Branch with their proper history data?

Comment: If you merged them, the log would have preserved them. You can't see that with `svn log` / `svn blame`, but you _can_ see that with `svn log --use-merge-history` & `svn blame --use-merge-history`. And when you're merging back to trunk, trunk will know what is already has, and what is yours.

Comment: See it like this: _you_ committed the merge, so _you_ are the 'main' committer, but `svn` _also_ remembers where those changes originated. However, I wouldn't know how to show that in `websvn`, which seems quite limited. I would keep merges & new code in separate commits though, but that's just a personal preference, it isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you.  I spoke with another developer on the project about it, and he confirmed that the best workflow would be to do a commit ('mering trunk to branch...') immediately after merging, so I keep my edits in a separate commit, as you suggested.